# One to Many relationship in Express Models using mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, model

This is `doctors.js` model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Patient = require('./patient.js');

var doctorSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  qualifications: String,
  photo: Buffer,
  _patients: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Patient' }]
});

var Doctor = mongoose.model('Doctor', doctorSchema);
module.exports = Doctor;
```

This is `patients.js` model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Doctor = require('./doctor.js');

var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  dob: String,
  gender: String,
  primaryDiagnosis: String,
  duration: String,
  _doctorIncharge: {type: Number, ref: 'Doctor'},
  hospitalNumber: String,
  photo: Buffer
});

var Patient = mongoose.model('Patient', patientSchema);
module.exports = Patient;
```

Is this the way to make a one to many relationship work?